# Preventing user deletion in Ruby On Rails and Devise Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails 3.2.x application using Devise.

As per standard Devise feature, a user can delete his account (there is a button to click on the change passsword screen).

I want to prevent a user of deleting his account if he has made previous transactions in the system.

So I did the following in the user model

```
before_destroy do
    # Only delete if no financial transactions exist
    return false if Trxhistory.where(:user_id=>self.id).select(:id).count() != 0
end
```

It works, the user gets deleted if no transactions exist and the user does not get deleted if a transaction exists.  BUT: in case the user is not deleted, the screen still shows the deletion success message rather than the error message.

Comment: Can you show controller code?

Comment: I am using standard Devise, I have not overwritten their controller.

Comment: I think you should do this to handle exception and show error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have such customization. I believe that you will have to overwrite the devise registrations controller.

The good news is that is not hard. all you have to do is generate a new controller on your app that will be the new registration controller for that user. for example.

```
bundle exec rails generate controller users/registrations
```

It will have to inherit from Devise:RegistrationsController

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

end
```

lastly you will have to reference this controller as the new registration controller at your routes.rb file just like the [devise page says](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations"}
```

now you can implement your custom rule for that resource. i.e

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def destroy
    if resource.didsomething
      redirect_to root_path, flash: { error: "You can't delete your account" }
    else
      super
    end 
  end 
end
```

the method above is overwriting the default destruction method of devise and calling the original one only if the condition is not met.